# Somewhat complex list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to filter a two-dimensional array, let's say

```
[
  [1, 'eth0', 'description', ...],
  [2, 'virbr0', 'description', ...],
  [3, 'qvb25f982e4-ae', 'description', ...],
  [4, 'tap25f982e4-ae', 'description', ...],
...
]
```

Basically I want to filter out certain interface names. I filter out interfaces starting with `q` like so:

```
info = [i for i in info if not i[1].startswith('q')]
```

But I need to be able to define a list of interface prefixes to ignore, like:

```
exclude = ['q','tap']
info = [i for i in info if not i[1].startswith(exclude)]
```

But I can't seem to work out the logic for something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're SO close!.  Turn `exclude` into a *tuple*:

```
exclude = ('q','tap')
info = [i for i in info if not i[1].startswith(exclude)]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> ... *prefix* can also be a **tuple**<sup>1</sup> of prefixes to look for....

---

demo:

```
>>> info = [
...   [1, 'eth0', 'description'],
...   [2, 'virbr0', 'description'],
...   [3, 'qvb25f982e4-ae', 'description'],
...   [4, 'tap25f982e4-ae', 'description'],
... ]
>>> 
>>> exclude = ('q','tap')
>>> info = [i for i in info if not i[1].startswith(exclude)]
>>> 
>>> info
[[1, 'eth0', 'description'], [2, 'virbr0', 'description']]
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>I added the emphasis...</sup>

Comment: @Sammitch -- No problem.  It's always nice to see original questions that are that close to the correct answer.